Commas before participle clauses
We sometimes use a comma before a participle clause:

There's Neville, eating as usual.


In came the first runner, closely followed by the second.


A little girl walked past, her doll dragging behind her on the pavement.


The bomb exploded, destroying the building

And sometimes not:

We can offer you a job cleaning cars.


I found him sitting at a table covered with papers.

How does it work?

In many cases we use a comma where it would be natural to make a slight pause in speech.
In your last two examples, it would be wrong to include a comma. Cleaning cars is what the job consists of, not an added description. A table covered with papers is where 'he' was sitting. If there was a comma there, it would suggest that 'he' was covered in papers! (Compare I found him sitting at a table, drinking tea.)

Can you say it works similarly to defining and non-defining relative clauses?

Yes, that's exactly what it is!

So "There's Neville, eating as usual." means "There's Neville, who is eating as usual" and "We can offer you a job cleaning cars." means "We can offer you a job which is cleaning cars."? (Note the use of the commas)

Yes, that is what I meant.
